# $\phi^3$-theory decay: Feynman rules

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, feynman-diagrams

My question is very basic since I started reading about quantum field theory only a few weeks ago.

Given the Lagrangian $$ L = -\frac{1}{2}\phi(\Box+m^2)\phi+\frac{g}{3!}\phi^3,$$

I would like to draw the tree-level Feynman Diagram for the decay $\phi \to \phi\phi$ and compute the amplitude using the Feynman rules in momentum space.

My idea is that the Feynman Diagram consists simply of one vertex and three lines connecting to that vertex (one standing for the incoming $\phi$ and two standing for the outgoing $\phi$'s). Since there are no internal lines, there are no propagators involved, and the vertex gives a factor of $i g$, where $g$ is the coupling constant from the Lagrangian. However, I'm not sure what to do with the momenta of the incoming and outgoing fields. I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: The vertex also gives a $\delta (p_{1}+p_{2}+p_{3})$  for momentum conservation.

Comment: @tsufli Thank you, but is this it? What would be the result?

Comment: The result would actually be $M=-g$. See Peskin&Schroeder equation 4.73 for a definition of scattering amplitude.  The convention is to eat up the momentum conservation, a $(2\pi)^{4}$ and an i in the definition. If you were computing, for example a momentum space correlation function instead, you would need all of those and the external propagators as well